# How do I match Microsoft AutoML text label Predictions with Scores?

Tags: c#, .net-core, automl

I have a Text Classification model that was generated within Microsoft's C# autoML wizard.

The auto generated ModelOutput object has a `Prediction` field which is a single text label and a `Scores[]` array which is a list of the probabilities.

My problem is that I don't know how to match each score with each label.

Is there an ENUM or an array of labels somewhere in this auto-generated code where I can match the labels 1:1 with the scores?